# Object disapear/don't scale in the Z-AXIS of OPENGL

Tags: opengl

This code is susposed to have a QUAD orbit around a center point in basically a circle. The problem is while it does the X rotation fine it disapears when it moves in Z axis and doesn't appear to change in size. It feel like it's rendering everything in Orthagraphic view or something.

This is my first OpenGL project.

OPENGL CODE START HERE

```
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);

        glPushMatrix();
       //glRotatef(theta, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
       glScalef(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f);
       glTranslatef(planeX, -0.0f, 0.0f);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(0.0f,   0.0f, planeZ);
            glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(0.0f,   1.0f, planeZ);
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1.0f,   1.0f, planeZ);
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1.0f,   0.0f, planeZ);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();

        SwapBuffers(hDC);

        theta += 1.0f;

        planeX = (sin(0.0314159265f*theta));
        planeZ = (cos(0.0314159265f*theta));
        Sleep (1);
```

ENDS HERE

Comment: Where's the code where you set your GL_MODELVIEW matrix?

Comment: @genpfault; more like, where's the code where he sets the projection matrix (yes, this one does, but it should be setting the modelview matrix)

Comment: If the code isn't there then there probably isn't a GL_MODELVIEW Matrix or Projection matrix

Answer (score 2):

[Help stamp out GL_PROJECTION abuse.](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html)